# Charting with 500K data points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to plot scatter chart which has more than 500,000 data points. I tried with `highcharts` but doesn't seems to work fine.

Please suggests any other charts which can handle such huge data or any other solutions using highcharts.

Comment: "lakh" meaning 100.000?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work ? Is it a performance issue ?

Comment: Any example, jsFiddle please?

Comment: check this http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold. set turbo threshold to null and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Highstock, not Highcharts, for example 1.7 million with async loading: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading